# How to create an alert in splunk if a count of a given field:value pair is greater than 5

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I am new to splunk and need to query for a particular field. The events look something like this:

```
[2022-08-27 10:49:54.909.196][0x0000219c][Info][GENERAL] Player{
    PlayerName: popeye
    Experience: 32
}


[2022-08-27 10:49:54.909.196][0x0000219c][Info][GENERAL] Player{
    PlayerName: jack
    Experience: 12
}

[2022-08-27 10:49:54.909.196][0x0000219c][Info][GENERAL] Player{
    PlayerName: popeye
    Experience: 32
}

[2022-08-27 10:49:54.909.196][0x0000219c][Info][GENERAL] Player{
    playerName: popeye
    experience: 32
}
```

I want to create an alert if any unique PlayerName count is greater than 2. For example, in this case there would be an alert for "popeye".

I was able to extract the field and the count using |stats count by playerName,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you tried `|stats count by playerName` but not what results you got from that.  I suspect you got nothing because there is no 'playerName' field.  Field names are case-sensitive.  Try

```
| stats count by PlayerName
| where count > 2
```

Of course, that presumes the PlayerName field is extracted already.